# Accessing array of numbers in ARM (with Komodo compilation)

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm

I'm implementing a bubble sort for university in ARM, and have a list of numbers defined in a word.

```
array DEFW 10, 15, 44, 7
```

I've then got my fully working loop to go through each item, using a hard-coded array size value. However, I don't understand how I can access the different items in the array. The specification tells us to use the index like prepended by a hash, but I don't understand quite how to do this. I've tried various combinations of the variable name, indexes, square brackets - it just isn't working.

Can anybody give me some pointers? I'm running Komodo (KMD) arm debugger to test.

Comment: In the absence of code, actual error messages, etc., it's really not clear what exactly you're asking, and what the actual problem is. At a guess it _sounds_ like consulting your assemly language reference for the difference between [immediate-offset LDR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289873425.html) and [register-offset LDR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289874275.html) would serve you well.

Comment: Sorry for not being much help NotLikeThat. That's what I've also tried, though I'm getting "Bad Register" pointing to the start of the word "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. Solution:

```
ADR r0, array
LDR r0, [r0,#4] ; 4 is the size of each item, change when you need to
SWI 4
```